# .Net MVC 3 View is not loading Layout

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

I have created a view that should act as a master page(`_MasterAccount.cshtml`) with the following code:

```
<h1>TEST!!!!</h1>
@RenderBody()
<h1>TEST!!!!</h1>
```

I tried to have another view reference it using the following code:

```
@{ 
   ViewBag.Title = "My account - Options";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_MasterAccount.cshtml";
 }
```

I am using RAZOR and there isn't a `_viewstart.cshtml` in the project

For some reason the layout is being ignored. It doesn't even throw an exception when I put in a non existing path.

Please note that there is already a "main" master page and mine is acting as a nested master page for specific set of pages.

The site has been developed by someone else, so I am suspecting that there is a piece of code that is overloading the layout property somehow. Thing is, I don't know where to look.

Please let me know if additional information is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in 2 answers from stack overflow.

A view engine was implemented in the system to locate the master pages, therefore the **layout** field was being ingored. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632964/can-i-specify-a-custom-location-to-search-for-views-in-asp-net-mvc) answer.

Therefore to implement the master within the master I opted for this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357104/is-is-possible-to-specify-searchable-location-formats-for-an-mvc-razor-layout) although it looks a bit messy.